# Type checking fails for custom control?

Tags: c#, winforms, types

I have a custom class that extends `TextBox`, defined in ParentNamespace.Controls.NumberBox.cs, which resides in its own directory.

```
namespace ParentNamespace
{
    namespace Controls
    {
        public class NumberBox : TextBox
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

I have a UserControl I've created called `ColumnControl`, which has a `NumberBox` on it. `ColumnControl` is its own project that has included ParentNamespace.Controls.NumberBox.cs as a linked existing item.

I have a Windows Forms project that adds a `ColumnControl` onto its Form, and also references ParentNamespace.Controls.NumberBox.cs as a linked existing item.

Now here comes the trouble:

In my WinForms project, I am trying to typecheck all controls on the form to find all `TextBox` and all `NumberBox` controls. The typecheck works fine for `TextBox` controls inside my `ColumnControl`. However, I am unable to detect my `NumberBox` on the `ColumnControl` for some reason.

Every control runs through this code:

```
private static IEnumerable<Control> EnumerateControlsByType(Control control, Type type = null)
{
    IEnumerable<Control> controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();

    foreach (Control c in controls)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(c.Name + " = " + c.GetType().ToString() + "  [== " + type.ToString() + "? " + (c.GetType() == type).ToString() + "]");
    }

    return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => EnumerateControlsByType(ctrl, type))
                              .Concat(controls)
                              .Where(c => (type == null || c.GetType() == type));
    }
}
```

And the debug looks like this:

```
myTextBox = System.Windows.Forms.TextBox  [== System.Windows.Forms.TextBox? True]
//...
myNumberBox = ParentNamespace.Controls.NumberBox  [== ParentNamespace.Controls.NumberBox? False]
```

As you can see, the `GetType()` strings are exactly the same for `myNumberBox` and for the type I pass to `EnumerateControlsByType`, which I'm just passing the type like so:

```
typeof(ParentNamespace.Controls.NumberBox)
```

But nonetheless, the typecheck returns false, and I can't detect my `NumberBox`.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You would need to post a better code example for someone else to diagnose the problem. My only thought at the moment is "why not use the `is` operator?", but given the debug output you show, that's not likely to be related to the actual problem.

Comment: @Peter: You can't use `is` operator with a Type variable, only with the explicit type itself written out

Comment: @Grant: I mean, I added .cs by choosing Add > Existing Item > Add as Link (so it's not actually copied into my project, it's just referenced)

Comment: @jramm: sure, but you could write the method as a generic so that the actual type is available. The only reason you seem to be using `typeof` here is specifically to get an instance of `Type` you can pass and compare with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use "Add As Link". Even though you know it's the same class, your program doesn't. It sees the multiple files as different classes that have different types.

If you need to reference your class from multiple projects, place the class in a separate project, right-click "References" and choose "Add Reference" to add that project.

Comment: Hmm, I was afraid of that, which is why I made sure to mention it in the post.. Alright. So would I need to create a class library to include in the other projects?

Comment: I think it is probably best for me to restructure things a bit and put the `ColumnControl` and the other custom controls into a single control library, things are a bit sloppy right now since I'm still getting familiar with C#. In any case, the problem is clear to me now, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Re-reading the heavily edited question, I see the problem:

> ColumnControl is its own project that has included `ParentNamespace.Controls.NumberBox.cs` as a linked existing item

I.e. you have declared the `NumberBox` type in two different assemblies. The one in your program and which you are passing as the type for your enumeration method is completely different from the one in your `UserControl` assembly (and which is used in the actual form).

You should simply make the `NumberBox` type that's declared in the `UserControl` assembly, and then reference that type from your program instead of linking the source code. Alternatively, if you want to use the `NumberBox` type in a context where you don't want the `UserControl` assembly, it would need to go into a third DLL that both the program and the `UserControl` assembly reference.